# I am stucked while hMailServer server database setup and it is showing following error

Tags: hmail-server

Error:

```
The MySQL client (libmysql.dll, 32 bit) could not be loaded.
hMailServer needs this file to be able to connect to MySQL.
The MySQL client needs to be manually copied to the hMailServer Bin directory. The file is not included in the hMailServer installation.
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\hMailServer\Bin\libmysql.dll
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory.  *Did you copy* the dll and test it?

Comment: @Nic3500 Yes. I already did. Thanks problem solved. Actually it was about selecting database for server.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more complicated.
You should read this Article which explain why it can be problematic with hMailServer 5.6.x
and MySQL 8.x or higher

Support article:
https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=33531

MySQL-Archive Downloads for MySQL 5.x compatible libmysql.dll versions
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/